# Win32 file permission sharing violation while deleting a temporary file

Tags: winapi, file-permissions

I have an application where I am trying to implement a "safe file overwrite" by:

1. Creating a file (`A`)
2. Filling  `A` with data
3. Copying `A` to its final destination (`B`) via [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28VS.85%29.aspx)
4. Deleting `A` using [`DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915%28VS.85%29.aspx)

However in step 4 `DeleteFile` always returns ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION. The entire process takes milliseconds, so I can't imagine who else would be interfering with my file. A couple questions:

1. Is there a better Win32 (C/C++) technique for performing the above?
2. How can I get more information about the "other process" that's keeping me from deleting file `A`?
3. How do I gently (*wink wink nudge nudge*) force Windows to delete my temporary file?

Any other suggestions are welcome

Comment: Could you paste the code for all steps?

Comment: Are you running antivirus s/w?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess would be that you need a step 2.5) Close the file handle created in 1)

What are you using to create/open the file?

If you use CreateFile then make sure you are closing your file handle before the call to delete, or else make sure you specify the sharing flag `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("C:\\test.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE |  FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
```

You might also want to simplify your copying of file code by using the Win32 API [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

One way to delete the file would be to open it with [`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) which will request the OS to automatically delete the file after the last handle to it is closed. If you create the file with `FILE_SHARE_READ` then `SHFileOperation` should be able to read it to copy it, and you can then immediately close your handle to the file. When the shell closes *its* handle to the file, the file will be automatically deleted.

Comment: I think he has this problem on every use of his function though, so this shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

- Try using Handles.exe from www.sysinternals.com to see if and how the file is in use.
- You can use GetLastError and FormatMessage to get further information about the last failed function:

Some sample code:

```
char tx2[1024];

DWORD l;

if(l = GetLastError())
{
    LPVOID lpMessageBuffer = 0;
    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL,
        l,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), //The user default language
        (LPTSTR) &lpMessageBuffer,    
        0,
        NULL
    );

    SetLastError(0);
    MessageBox(NULL, tx2, "MyApplication", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK | (MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_TOPMOST | MB_TASKMODAL));
}
```